# Custom Content Type creation in a List

Tags: content-type

Is it possible to create a content type in such a way that Document Library, Task, Calendar & Discussion Board can be created in a single list?

Does it require some hard core programming ?

Please help!

-saumil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Types just identify attributes of content.  You can create a Content Type that can be used by any of those list types as long as the base content type it relates to is generic.

The specialized functionality that comes with specific list types like the Calendar or Discussion Board are backed into those List Definitions.  So you cannot create all of those behavior types in a single list/library.  You can in a single site though, and by using a unified Contnet Type, it will be easy to join or aggregate the content.

Comment: Mike, that was a very wonderful and to-the-point answer, thanks!